# Windows is not detected by grub in Lubuntu after update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I've had a dual boot Windows 8.1/Lubuntu 16.04 for over a year. I use Windows for my main work and Lubuntu for practicing Linux.

I logged into Lubuntu after 3 months of inactivity and ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` . I am unable to see Windows on startup, only Ubuntu and other recovery options for Linux are available. Moreover I checked in BIOS about UEFI. It's all fine.
I am unable to mount. GParted shows Windows not mounted and `lsblk` looks like this:

[image: gparted shows windows not mounted and lsblk looks like this]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I also installed ntfs-3g.

Please suggest a way to recover Windows.

Comment: You need to repair your NTFS partition. The error that gparted shows will also prevent any Linux tools see the partition. You may just need chkdsk from your Windows repair disk, or may need to make sure Windows is not hibernated, nor that fast start up is on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for sparing your time to answer my question.
My problem got solved after I installed boot-repair and gave recommended actions.

I reinstalled and now I can see windows back.

Comment: @Yaron Despite the confusing "thank you" in it this is a unique answer to the question that says the problem was solved by running Boot Repair.

Answer (score 0):

ntfs-3g ist most probably not the problem as there is more ntfs partitions without errors… (You don't neet ntfs-3g until you want to read/write data from/to NTFS (Windows) partitions in Ubuntu.)

Do I get you right, that you can't boot into Windows as it is not present in the grub boot list?

Is an entry for Windows present in /etc/grub.d/grub.cfg?

If not, did you run `sudo update-grub` to update the grub list? Is it present afterwards?

Best,
dom